# Python - Change Column Names, Merge and Re-Order a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames - DataFrameA and DataFrameB

DataFrameA

```
ID   ColA  ColB  ColC
1    12    23    40
2    21    24    45
3    23    31    50
```

DataFrameB

```
ID   ColA  ColB  ColC
1    21    23    40
2    20    44    45
3    29    51    70
4    49    51    70
```

I want an output DataFrame like this,

Prefix for DataFrame B Columns declared in a variable = "BBBBB"

DataFrameC

```
ID  ColA    BBBBB.ColA  ColB    BBBBB.ColB  ColC    BBBBB.ColC
1   12       21         23       23          40      40
2   21       20         24       44          45      45
3   23       29         31       51          50      70
```

I am doing an Inner Join between DataFrame A and Data Frame B and sorting the columns in order after that.

The DataFrameA and DataFrameB are Pandas dataframe. So prefer a pandas method.

Comment: If you really want a suffix, and not a prefix like your output example, use `df1.join(df2, on='ID', rsuffix='.BBBBB')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

```
yourdf=dfa.merge(dfb.add_prefix('BBBBB.'),left_on='ID',right_on='BBBBB.ID')
yourdf
Out[219]: 
   ID  ColA  ColB     ...      BBBBB.ColA  BBBBB.ColB  BBBBB.ColC
0   1    12    23     ...              21          23          40
1   2    21    24     ...              20          44          45
2   3    23    31     ...              29          51          70
[3 rows x 8 columns]
```

If need reorder

```
yourdf.reindex(columns=sorted(yourdf.columns,key=lambda x : x.split('.')[-1]))
```

Comment: Re-ordering is another thing